# Calling another function through eval by passing arguments in Perl

Tags: perl, dynamic

I have written the following code for passing arguments to eval function in sample.pl and calling the function in another Perl file sample1.pl.

sample1.pl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
require 'sample.pl';
use subs "hello";
my $main2 = hello();
sub hello
 {
   print "Hello World!\n";
    our $a=10;
    our $b=20;
    my $str="sample.pl";
    my $xc=eval "sub{$str($a,$b)}";
 }
```

Sample.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;
our $a;
our $b;
use subs "hello_world";
my $sdf=hello_world();
sub hello_world($a,$b)
 { 
    print "Hello World!\n";
    our $c=$a+$b;   
    print "This is the called function from sample !\n";
    print "C: " .$c;

 } 1;
```

I am getting output as:

```
Illegal character in prototype for main::hello_world : $a,$b at D:/workspace/SamplePerl_project/sample.pl line 6.
Use of uninitialized value $b in addition (+) at D:/workspace/SamplePerl_project/sample.pl line 9.
Use of uninitialized value $a in addition (+) at D:/workspace/SamplePerl_project/sample.pl line 9.
Hello World!
This is the called function from sample !
C: 0Hello World!
```

can u guys show me a solution for this how to call a function through eval by passing arguments

Comment: so much is wrong here. eval is used to compile and run  string, not read a file and execute it. if you want to execute a separate file in perl use backticks (as one solution)

Comment: Let's take a step back and consider. What are you actually trying to do? Is this a smiplification of a problem, or have you just started learning Perl? Do you have a concrete task that you need to accomplish? Please take a moment to explain what your ultimate goal is.

Comment: You should never have to use `our` except for `@ISA`. Use `my`! And use variables other than `$a` and `$b` as those are used by `sort`.

Comment: Don't use [`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html "perldoc eval") until you are a more experienced Perl programmer. Almost everything you can do with it can be done more safely another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this This will help u..

```
         my $action="your function name";
         if ($action) {
             eval "&$action($a,$b)";
         }
```

in Receiving function

```
   sub your function name {
      my ($a,$b) =@_;#these are the arguments 
   }
```

Comment: What if `$a` and `$b` are not integers but strings, or, worse, references?

Answer (score 8):

> how to call a function through eval by passing arguments?

```
sub func {
    print join(", ", @_), "\n";
    return 99; 
}

my ($str, $a, $b) = ('func', 10, 'tester');
my $f = eval "\\&$str" or die $@;
my $c = $f->($a, $b);
print "c = $c\n";
```

But there's need to use `eval`. The above can be written as

```
my $f = \&$str;
my $c = $f->($a, $b);
```

or even

```
my $c = (\&$str)->($a, $b);
```

Comment: What if `$a` and `$b` are not integers but strings, or, worse, references?

Comment: or `eval $str.'($a, $b)'` would have worked (with regards to el.pescado's point).

Comment: @Chris, yeah, but what perreal posted is much better.